# HTML DataTables render a function in the cell

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have a JavaScript function that creates the DataTable. For the first cell in each row, I want to render a vizualisation function (with 3Dmol.js library) and display the object in this cell. The 3Dmol.js requires a container where the function result should be placed (the element variable). I want to choose the current cell. I tried with $(this); but I get an error saying: "Uncaught error creating viewer: TypeError: div.getBoundingClientRect is not a function"

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

      var in_json = '{{ in_json }}'

      $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#fragmenterTable').DataTable({
          'ajax': { url: in_json, dataSrc: 'data' },
          "scrollX": true,
          "scrollY": 200,
          "autoWidth": false,

          "columnDefs": [
            {
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return function viz_frag(data) {
                      var glviewer = null;
                      data = data 
                      let element = $(this);

                      glviewer = $3Dmol.createViewer(element, "gldiv");
                      glviewer.addModel(data,'mol2');
                      glviewer.setStyle({},{stick:{}});
                      glviewer.zoomTo()
                      glviewer.zoom(2,1000);
                      
                      glviewer.render();

                      glviewer.setBackgroundColor(0xffffff);

    };
                },
                "targets": 0
            },
            { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 3 ] }
        ]

        });
        $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
      });
    </script>
```

What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: Can you pls provide some js file with some sample data for this? I never ever used 3Dmol before. however I think the problem is that you are creating a new event inside the column, when maybe your objective is to create a new event inside some cell, if the row itself contains the necessary data to this approach you could add a button inside the row or some click event to trigger this functionallity sorry for the bad english